# Changing a workbooks "FullName" property in the "Workbook_BeforeSave" event

Tags: excel, vba

I need to rename a workbook to the name of a cell when the user clicks "Save" or "Save as". My guess is that I would need to do this in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. I have the following questions:

- How do you set the `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` property with out calling `Save`, `SaveAs`, or `SaveCopyAs`?
- Is what I am trying to do even possible without disabling the toolbar and adding custom save buttons?

I use the following code to get create the filename

```
Dim fName As String, sName As String
fName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sName = ThisWorkbook.Name    
fName = Left(fName, (Len(fName) - Len(sName))) & _ 
         Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Cust").Range("FILE").Value & ".xls"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the Name or Fullname properties except through a save operation.  The Before_Save event has a Cancel argument that if you set to True will stop the save operation and let you do it yourself.  Here's an example.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim sOldName As String

    'If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True 'cancel the save and do it yourself in code
        sOldName = Me.FullName 'store the old name so you can delete it later

        'Save using the value in the cell
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.SaveAs Me.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                Me.Worksheets("CUST").Range("FILE").Value & ".xls"
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        'If the name changed, delete the old file
        If Me.FullName <> sOldName Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Kill sOldName
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

    'End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I see that it only works for when you click "SaveAs". Is there any way to do this for just "Save". Also it doesn't show the browser, is there a way to show it? Finally, thanks for the simpler file naming code. -theo

Comment: I messed that up.  Remove the If SaveAsUI Then and the corresponding End If and it will work with Save also.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it ended up canceling every save. I was able to get around it by putting the cancel behind an If statement that looked at a global boolean to see if workbook_beforesave had been called before. Gotta love recursion!

Comment: Bah!  I really made a mess of that.  I've edited to comment out the saveasui lines and added two lines around the SaveAs that temporarily disables events.

Comment: Worked like a charm and is much more elegant than my solution. Thank you very much!